# what is the minimum number of hints must be provide in a Sudoku with only one solution in order to reach the answer?

Tags: reference-request, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

what is the minimum number of hints must be provide in a Sudoku with only one solution in order to reach the answer?

Also if you are interested, please provide a reference.

Comment: If by "hints" you mean the number of filled cells of a standard 9x9 grid, there are examples (with unique solution) having 17 "hints".  No examples with fewer filled cells are known, but it's conjectured that this is the minimum required for a unique solution.

Comment: Note that typing the text of your question: "what is the minimum number of hints must be provide in a Sudoku" into Google would have given you all that is in my answer...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Typing it into Math Stack Exchange also works.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was going to say that typing the question into Google might not give Victor all the *comments* your answer is going to get. But I would have been wrong: the first Google hit is this page at MSE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According this [this link](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/426554/mathematicians-solve-minimum-sudoku-problem/), $17$ is the smallest number of hints.

The paper is at http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.0749 .

Comment: Some commentary on the paper is given [here](http://www.sudokuwiki.org/17_Clue_Proof), on a website devoted to constructing sudoku solvers and related software.